# Proper Usage of Parentheses in Variable Declaration

Tags: java, integer

I'm trying to grasp a concept within Java programming and came across the following line of code:

```java
int insertPerson(UUID id, Person person);
```

This code snippet is part of an interface named `PersonDao`. Within this interface, there's a method declaration `insertPerson` which takes two parameters: a `UUID` named `id` and an instance of the `Person` class named `person`.

Here's the interface for context:

```
public interface PersonDao {

    int insertPerson(UUID id, Person person);

    default int addPerson(Person person) {
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        return insertPerson(id, person);
    }
}
```

Could someone please provide a detailed explanation of the code line `int insertPerson(UUID id, Person person);`? How does this fit into the broader structure of the `PersonDao` interface and the `addPerson` method? Your guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's an abstract method

Comment: That's not a variable declaration.  That's defining a method signature for the interface which would need to be implemented by any class implementing the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [`abstract`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020664/5761558) [`public`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43465060/5761558) method with `int` as the return type, not a variable/property. `PersonDao` being an interface, it accepts abstract methods.

Both `public` and `abstract` are implicit modifiers of the method. So it's equivalent to the following declaration:

```
public abstract int insertPerson(UUID id, Person person);
```